# How to implement dynamic filtering of data in React.js App?

Tags: reactjs, filter, filtering

How to implement dynamic filtering of data in React.js App?
I have to sort the data in the standard ways Ascending A-z and then Z-a,Ascending Price and Descending Price.How can I do it?
I think about having a separate pages ordered in this specific way and when the user presses it to show them the new page.

```
 <aside class="vegnv">
            <button className="btne" >V</button>
            <button className="btne" >Non V</button>
            <button className="btne" >A-z</button>
            <button className="btne" >Z-a</button>
            <button className="btne" >Price +</button>
            <button className="btne" >Price -</button>
        </aside>
```

and something like this to filter the data

```
  {recipessh.filter(x=>x.name.sort((a,b) a.localeCompare(b)).map(x => <RecipeShared key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)}
```

Also isn't it fundamentally wrong to force an React Application to rerender? I should use only JS for the task.